# How to display tooltip content on top of bar in Column chart in Canvas.js?

Tags: canvas, tooltip

I want to display tooltip on top of each bar on mouse over in Column Chart. I am using canvas.js plugin to draw graph. http://canvasjs.com/

Comment: CanvasJS has [built in tooltips](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/tool-tip/) that hover over the data representations.

Comment: It will display tooltip just beside on your mouse pointer, i would like to fix it's position on top of bar that means it should not follow mouse pointer.